# Python recursively finding the son of a parent

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I am actually learning how to apply recursion to solve some real life problems. Let's say, I have a dictionary that stores a family tree, and each person's children will be stored in this dictionary and its level in the tree too. I want to find out the sub-tree of a family and store it into a separate dictionary, so I have to keep checking if this person has a children. However, I don't know why the new dictionary of my recursive function can only store those people that have no child.

```
dict[1] = [[2,3], 2] #the first one is the children list, the second one is the level in the family tree

newDict = {}
subtree = findSub(dict, 2, 0, newDict)

#my newDict is an empty dictionary, newDict= {}
#level stores the person's level in the tree
def findSub(dict, parent, level, newDict):

    level += 1

    children = dict[parent][0]

    if (len(children) == 0):
        info = [dict[parent][0], level]
        newDict[parent] = info

    else:
        for child in children:
            findSub(dict, child, level, newDict)

    return newDict
```

Comment: You probably want to use this: http://sedimental.org/remap.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I don't know why the new dictionary of my recursive function can only store those people that **have no child**.

```
def findSub(dict, parent, level, newDict):

    level += 1

    children = dict[parent][0]

    if (len(children) == 0):
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        info = [dict[parent][0], level]
   .....
```

This `if` checks if the element has no children. If it has children you recurse further, but you don't add the element before recursing further.

If you wanted to save even the parents (which in end will result in the whole subtree), you would do something like

```
def findSub(dict, parent, level, newDict):

    level += 1

    children = dict[parent][0]
    info = [dict[parent][0], level]
    newDict[parent] = info

    if (len(children) != 0):
        for child in children:
            findSub(dict, child, level, newDict)

    return newDict
```

Comment: Oh, it works well. I really want to know how can I master the concept of recursive function.

Comment: What helped me is learning the stack and it's mechanics (how the functions get put on it, and then removed from it after execution): http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Recursion/StackFramesImplementingRecursion.html